# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null?

Tags: javascript

when i used addEventlistener for DOMContentLoaded i got error in my console stating that cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.
And pls explain me how to solve this typeError?

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
    engine.enableOfflineSupport = false; // Dont require a manifest file
    var createScene = function(){
        var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color3.White();


        var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("arcCam",
                BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(0),
                BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(0),
                10.0,BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(),scene);
        camera.attachControl(canvas,true);
        var light = new BABYLON.PointLight("PointLight",new BABYLON.Vector3(
        0,0,0),scene);
        light.parent = camera;
        light.intensity = 1.5;

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("","","ShippingContainer.babylon",
        scene,function(newMeshes) {
            newMeshes.forEach(function(mesh){
                mesh.rotation = new BABYLON.Vector3(BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(
                45),0,0);
            }                );
        });

        return scene;
    }

    var scene = createScene();
    engine.runRenderLoop(function(){
        scene.render();
    });

});
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Try with `document.addEventListener(...`

Comment: It means that at the time of execution of that line your document does not have the element you tried to select. Please note that the `window` object only exists in the context of a browser, not in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML file. The script line that link your HTML file with your JS file will be in the head. Move it to the end of the body and this problem will dissappear.